# Delete first line of text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting, text-files

I need a cmd script that deletes the first line in my text file. The scenario is the following: I take a txt file from FTP everyday, the problem is that it comes with blank line at the top then the headers of the file. Since I'm importing that file automatically into an access table, that blank line is causing me problems.

So, I need a script that deletes the blank line and saves the file.

Comment: @Preet, he does say "cmd".  I assume that means Windows.

Comment: yes but I read that as typing shorthand for 'command' as a general term, not specifically windows

Answer (score 30):

Windows/command prompt:

```
more +1 filename.ext > otherfilename.ext
```

That seems to work fine, however it appears that this also converts tab characters into multiple spaces..
I needed to remove the first line of a tab-delimited file before importing into postgres.
That failed due to the automatic conversion of tabs to spaces by more...

Comment: +1: Nice to see that Microsoft has improved the more command. I had noticed that other commands where improved a lot, but missed this one.

Comment: -1: Have you tried with a file with lines of more than 15 Mb? It doesn't work at all

Comment: After 65535th line it hangs.

Comment: This command replaces tab by spaces !!! How to do without lost tab ?

Answer (score 9):

You didn't specify a platform.  Here's how to do it in any *NIX environment (and Windows+Cygwin):

```
sed -i~ 1d target-file
```

Comment: The same as above, it didn't worked with a very long line i.e. 24000000 characters or more

Answer (score 7):

To remove the first line, I would use

```
tail -n +2 source-file > target-file
```

If you want this on Windows, download the gnu utils to obtain a tail command. +2 means "Start at the second line".

Comment: If the source and target files are the same (which is likely), this clobbers that file.

Comment: You're right they should not be the same. However, they can be chosen by whoever writes the script.

Answer (score 7):

In windows without extra tools:

```
findstr /V /R "^$" filename.whatever
```

No extra tools needed

Comment: @Preet_Sangha i couldn't get this to work.  is there something i'm missing?

Comment: What happens? What is the input and what is output?

Comment: Should add that a simple output redirect gets the result into a file:
`findstr /V /R "^$" filename.whatever>clean_filename.whatever`
Also don't use same file for input and output! It'll put the file on 0b.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed some comments asking how to use Preet Sangha's solution.  As I do not have enough rep to add a comment, I wanted to post a more complete solution here.

You can use Preet Sangha's solution as follows.  This script will create a new text file without the first line of the input file.

```
findstr /V /R "^$" InputFile.txt > OutputFileNameWithFirstLineRemoved.txt
```

Comment: that would remove _any_ empty line (what seems to be wanted here; just to mention it for other searchers)

Comment: The solution provided by Preet Sangha was the best imho, I was able to process file with over 3GB in seconds!
BTW I used this code inside a BAT file to process multiple files (from smallest to largest)
`FOR /F %%a in ('dir /B /O:S *.sql') do (findstr /V /R "$" %%a > clean_%%a)`

Comment: @sangorys This has worked in every case that I have tested.  Can you provide any details on the encoding of file that you are using?

Comment: 1. It didn't remove the fist line for me. 2. it removed a lot of void lines in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do something similar today and this was what I came up with:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1" %A IN ('type "input_file.ext"') DO @echo %A>>"output_file.ext"
```

This has the advantage over the `more +1` solution in that tab characters will be preserved. However, on large files this method is a lot slower than others. Also - leading spaces will be left-trimmed, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: You can make it a lot faster for big files with `(for ...... do @echo/%A)>"output.ext"` (just one redirection). (Although it should be mentioned that this removes *every*  empty line)