# Using window commands to delete the first two lines of a text file

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, batch-file, xp-cmdshell

Can anyone provide a windows command or batch script that will remove the top two rows from a text file?

I'd like to remove the first two lines of a text file using findstr.  I can't use the "more +2 file.txt > newfile.txt" trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600653/delete-first-line) because i'm calling this via xp_cmdshell and that doesn't seem to work (process often hangs and creates a permanently locked file I can't delete).

I've heard that findstr can use regular expressions to find something like this, and i've seen some attempts using a bat file.  I'm open to either one of these possibilities but haven't found a working solution yet.

Comment: Could try the suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5451058/119246) or some of the others in answer to the same, it might work if the text file isn't huge.

Comment: @Darth_Continent tried those suggestions.  they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "myfile=%~1"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%myfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    for /f "delims=:" %%a in ("%%i") do set "row=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if !row! gtr 2 echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>newfile
type newfile
```

btw. syntax for `more`:

```
<file>newfile more +2
```

Comment: 1) replace the word `file` after `findstr` with the name of your file. 2) I made an edit, added `>` before `newfile`.

Comment: pretty cool!  Is it possible to pass in a file name as an argument?

Comment: it mostly works when i type my filename into the batch.  I have to delete newfile each time or the results get appended again.  IS it possible to pass in a filename when i run the batch instead?  e.g. "EndoroBatch.bat myfile.txt"?

Comment: Yes, now you can use your file name as parameter and the `newfile` will be always overwritten.